# WPF app - not clickable anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I am new to WPF and suddendly my Window is not clickable anymore.

I cannot click one button and I cannot edit a text box.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 (new to it as well).

What could be the reason?

here some code:

```
<Window x:Class="Mxx.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mxx"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="26*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Log out" Click="MenuItem_Click1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Option 2">
            <MenuItem Header="Load new control" Click="MenuItem_Click2a"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Open new window" Click="MenuItem_Click2b"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Border x:Name="Stage" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Grid x:Name="LoginLayer" Background="#FFFFFFFF" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="Mxx" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Name" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" MinWidth="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtName1" Background="Azure" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" MinWidth="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

            <TextBlock Text="Password" Grid.Row="2" Margin="3"/>
            <PasswordBox x:Name="txtPassword" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="3" MinWidth="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Button Click="Login_Click" Content="Log in" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3"/>

        </Grid>

        <TextBlock x:Name="lat1" Text="lat" Grid.Row="4" Margin="3"  />

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and here my main window

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _geoLocator = new Geolocator();
    Utils.getNetworkAdapterId();

    Debug.WriteLine("imei:  " + Properties.Settings.Default.imei);

    Properties.Settings.Default.imei = "imei1";

    Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); // Saves settings in application setting
}
```

my debugger hits the last line

Comment: Some code would be helpful. My second sight is a little foggy today.

Comment: There could be many reasons: running infinite loops (or long tasks) on UI thread, modal dialogs hiding behind your window, and so on.

Comment: Look into output window. What message it displays.

Comment: Or Debug->Break and look at the callstack(s) of your thread(s).

Comment: could you specify the point that is problem happened, I think the problem is in the event handlers, and I think also this problem happened after you executed some event handler

Comment: can you please show me the code of the event handler, the problems right there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is with the last declared TextBlock

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="lat1" Text="lat" Grid.Row="4" Margin="3"  />
```

That is outside of the grid that has row and column definitions, and so it is defaulting to taking up all the space in the page as an overlay.  You are unable to give focus to the controls beneath it.

You can see this in the XAML editor window.  In the code view, click on that element, and in the designer you will see that the textblock is the full size of your window.  Because it is declared last in the XAML, it take the uppermost position (z-index) and therefore "hides" the controls behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a TextBlock covering the other controls. I think you want to move lat1 into the /Grid tag directly above it.